# How to restrict directory access on an Azure Linux Web App (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, azure, azure-web-apps

I have an Azure Linux Web App, running PHP 8.2. Not that it is documented anywhere, but it is running Nginx 1.24.0 **NOT** IIS or Apache. I have verified this by looking at the `Server` response header of the pages it serves. Therefore, `web.config` or `.htaccess` files are not going to work.

I have translated the rules I want to Nginx config format fine, but I don't seem to have access to the config file (makes sense, people could probably do all sorts of stupid stuff if they could mess with that file). So how do I apply these settings? Does Nginx have some way of putting config settings in a sub-directory? Is there some other way I can do it?

Note: I don't care about performance - I am the only person that uses this site. I also know next to nothing about Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a guide on how to replace the in-built nginx config with one of your own:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/configure-nginx-for-php-8-linux-azure-app-service/ba-p/3069373

Essentially, you create your own config file (using the in-built one as a template) then configure a custom startup script for your container that copies your config file over the top of the existing one then restarts nginx.

The more nuclear option is to customise your own Docker image based off the one used in Azure and use App Service for Containers instead.